# Mining in geth Panic:Ethash_full_new IO or memory error

Tags: go-ethereum, console

i have already created my own private network and created my own account, i wanted to try to mine but when i do mining suddenly stops and i do not know what are the error that causes it i just see Ethash_full_new IO or  memory before it exits, im really new in geth so any help in debugging the commandline prompts will be really helpfull, here is the full cmd trace

```
C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\geth-tutorial-master\nugget1>geth --mine --datadir data
 --networkid 123 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 --verbosity 6 console
I0405 14:06:34.502420 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:34.506420 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling:
 libusb: not found [code -5]
I0405 14:06:34.508421 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:34.508421 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file h
andles to C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\geth-tutorial-master\nugget1\data\geth\chaind
ata
I0405 14:06:34.581428 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\
geth-tutorial-master\nugget1\data\geth\chaindata
I0405 14:06:34.582428 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1
.7.4
I0405 14:06:34.583428 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file h
andles to C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\geth-tutorial-master\nugget1\data\geth\chaind
ata
I0405 14:06:34.627433 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id
: 123
I0405 14:06:34.627433 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 0 Homestead: <
nil> DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: <nil> EIP158: <nil>}
I0405 14:06:34.628433 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #0 [659e16c3.] TD=163
84
I0405 14:06:34.628433 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #0 [659e16c3.] TD=1638
4
I0405 14:06:34.629433 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #0 [659e16c3.] TD=1638
4
I0405 14:06:34.630433 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1474] Quality of service: rtt
 20s, conf 1.000, ttl 1m0s
I0405 14:06:34.630433 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0405 14:06:34.631433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PrivateAdminAPI
under 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.632433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicAdminAPI u
nder 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.633433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *debug.HandlerT under
'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.634433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicDebugAPI u
nder 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.635433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *node.PublicWeb3API un
der 'web3'
I0405 14:06:34.636433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicCompiler
API under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.636433 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.CompilerAdminA
PI under 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.637434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicEthereum
API under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.637434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicBlockCha
inAPI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.638434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicTransact
ionPoolAPI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.639434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicTxPoolAP
I under 'txpool'
I0405 14:06:34.639434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicDebugAPI
 under 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.640434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PrivateDebugAP
I under 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.640434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicAccountA
PI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.641434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PrivateAccount
API under 'personal'
I0405 14:06:34.642434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PublicEthereumAPI
 under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.642434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PublicMinerAPI un
der 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.643434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *downloader.PublicDown
loaderAPI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.644434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PrivateMinerAPI u
nder 'miner'
I0405 14:06:34.644434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *filters.PublicFilterA
PI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.631433 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0405 14:06:34.635433 core/state/state_object.go:270] a94a1de6b03cb4ccb56778e67c
be8061092b870b: #0 1157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394550
84007913129639935 (- 2500000000000000000)
I0405 14:06:34.632433 eth/backend.go:473] Automatic pregeneration of ethash DAG
ON (ethash dir: C:\Users\aslaure\AppData\Ethash)
I0405 14:06:34.645434 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PrivateAdminAPI u
nder 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.648435 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PublicDebugAPI un
der 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.648435 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *eth.PrivateDebugAPI u
nder 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.646434 core/state/statedb.go:455] (+) fa7b9770ca4cb04296cac84f377
36d4041251cdf
I0405 14:06:34.650435 core/state/state_object.go:257] a94a1de6b03cb4ccb56778e67c
be8061092b870b: #1 1157920892373161954235709850086879078532699846656405640394575
82944313129639935 (+ 2498936400000000000)
I0405 14:06:34.651435 core/state/statedb.go:455] (+) 000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000
I0405 14:06:34.651435 core/state/state_object.go:257] 00000000000000000000000000
00000000000000: #0 1063600000000000 (+ 1063600000000000)
I0405 14:06:34.652435 internal/ethapi/api.go:578] call took 17.0017ms
I0405 14:06:34.653435 contracts/release/release.go:131] Release oracle not found
 at fa7b9770ca4cb04296cac84f37736d4041251cdf
I0405 14:06:34.650435 node/node.go:304] InProc registered *ethapi.PublicNetAPI u
nder 'net'
I0405 14:06:34.655435 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PrivateAdminAPI und
er 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.656435 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicAdminAPI unde
r 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.656435 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *debug.HandlerT under 'de
bug'
I0405 14:06:34.657436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicDebugAPI unde
r 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.657436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *node.PublicWeb3API under
 'web3'
I0405 14:06:34.658436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicCompilerAPI
 under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.658436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.CompilerAdminAPI
under 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.659436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicEthereumAPI
 under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.660436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicBlockChainA
PI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.660436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicTransaction
PoolAPI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.661436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicTxPoolAPI u
nder 'txpool'
I0405 14:06:34.662436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicDebugAPI un
der 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.662436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PrivateDebugAPI u
nder 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.663436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicAccountAPI
under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.664436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PrivateAccountAPI
 under 'personal'
I0405 14:06:34.664436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PublicEthereumAPI un
der 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.666436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PublicMinerAPI under
 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.666436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *downloader.PublicDownloa
derAPI under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.666436 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PrivateMinerAPI unde
r 'miner'
I0405 14:06:34.667437 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *filters.PublicFilterAPI
under 'eth'
I0405 14:06:34.668437 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PrivateAdminAPI unde
r 'admin'
I0405 14:06:34.668437 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PublicDebugAPI under
 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.669437 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *eth.PrivateDebugAPI unde
r 'debug'
I0405 14:06:34.670437 node/node.go:330] IPC registered *ethapi.PublicNetAPI unde
r 'net'
I0405 14:06:34.649435 eth/backend.go:480] checking DAG (ethash dir: C:\Users\asl
aure\AppData\Ethash)
I0405 14:06:34.671437 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
I0405 14:06:34.671437 miner/miner.go:136] Starting mining operation (CPU=4 TOT=5
)
I0405 14:06:34.673437 core/state/state_object.go:257] a94a1de6b03cb4ccb56778e67c
be8061092b870b: #0 5000000000000000000 (+ 5000000000000000000)
I0405 14:06:34.675437 miner/worker.go:517] commit new work on block 1 with 0 txs
 & 0 uncles. Took 2.0002ms
I0405 14:06:34.676437 miner/agent.go:111] (re)started agent[3]. mining...
I0405 14:06:34.676437 vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash/ethash.go:259] Generatin
g DAG for epoch 0 (size 1073739904) (0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000)
I0405 14:06:34.677438 miner/agent.go:111] (re)started agent[0]. mining...
I0405 14:06:34.677438 miner/agent.go:111] (re)started agent[1]. mining...
I0405 14:06:34.677438 miner/agent.go:111] (re)started agent[2]. mining...
I0405 14:06:34.800450 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"method
":"rpc_modules","params":null}
I0405 14:06:34.801450 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":1,"result":{"admin":"1.0","debug":"1.0","eth":"1.0","miner":"1.0","net":"1.0
","personal":"1.0","rpc":"1.0","txpool":"1.0","web3":"1.0"}}
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

I0405 14:06:34.811451 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":2,"method
":"web3_clientVersion","params":[]}
I0405 14:06:34.811451 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":2,"result":"Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1.7.4"}
instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1.7.4
I0405 14:06:34.815451 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":3,"method
":"eth_coinbase","params":[]}
I0405 14:06:34.816451 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":3,"result":"0xa94a1de6b03cb4ccb56778e67cbe8061092b870b"}
coinbase: 0xa94a1de6b03cb4ccb56778e67cbe8061092b870b
I0405 14:06:34.819452 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":4,"method
":"eth_blockNumber","params":[]}
I0405 14:06:34.820452 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":4,"result":"0x0"}
I0405 14:06:34.822452 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":5,"method
":"eth_blockNumber","params":[]}
I0405 14:06:34.822452 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":5,"result":"0x0"}
I0405 14:06:34.824452 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":6,"method
":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x0",false]}
I0405 14:06:34.825452 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":6,"result":{"difficulty":"0x4000","extraData":"0x","gasLimit":"0xffffffff","
gasUsed":"0x0","hash":"0x659e16c34884d73927ddf39a175e43a6d4a8a6a1301df60c75288d8
8a1e64be5","logsBloom":"0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","miner":"0x000000000
0000000000000000000000000000000","mixHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000","nonce":"0x0000000000000042","number":"0x0","par
entHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","r
eceiptsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421
","sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d493
47","size":"0x1fb","stateRoot":"0x6c14af2d40637762c58964d3043331563e15456a8177a9
b4ef02f017d683a3c1","timestamp":"0x0","totalDifficulty":"0x4000","transactions":
[],"transactionsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb
5e363b421","uncles":[]}}
at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 08:00:00 CST)
I0405 14:06:34.833453 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":7,"method
":"admin_datadir","params":[]}
I0405 14:06:34.833453 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":7,"result":"C:\\Users\\aslaure\\Desktop\\geth-tutorial-master\\nugget1\\data
"}
 datadir: C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\geth-tutorial-master\nugget1\data
I0405 14:06:34.839454 rpc/client.go:412] sending {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":8,"method
":"rpc_modules","params":null}
I0405 14:06:34.839454 rpc/client.go:505] <-readResp: response {"jsonrpc":"2.0","
id":8,"result":{"admin":"1.0","debug":"1.0","eth":"1.0","miner":"1.0","net":"1.0
","personal":"1.0","rpc":"1.0","txpool":"1.0","web3":"1.0"}}
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txp
ool:1.0 web3:1.0

> I0405 14:06:36.733643 p2p/nat/nat.go:109] network port tcp:30303 could not be
mapped: no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered
I0405 14:06:37.508721 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:40.511021 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:43.512321 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:46.513621 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
I0405 14:06:49.520922 accounts/keystore/account_cache.go:228] reloaded keys, cac
he has 1 accounts
panic: ethash_full_new IO or memory error

goroutine 80 [running]:
panic(0xc4d900, 0x14480030)
        C:/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x331
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*dag).generat
e.func1()
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum
/ethash/ethash.go:273 +0x4d3
sync.(*Once).Do(0x13544a94, 0x1358fc00)
        C:/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xcf
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*dag).generat
e(0x13544a80)
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum
/ethash/ethash.go:277 +0x3d
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*Full).getDAG
(0x13644540, 0x1, 0x0, 0x13544a80)
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum
/ethash/ethash.go:333 +0xae
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum/ethash.(*Full).Search
(0x13644540, 0x12a1ee0, 0x13666820, 0x134a6980, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/ethereum
/ethash/ethash.go:338 +0x71
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*CpuAgent).mine(0x138838f0, 0x13604c40, 0
x134a6980)
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/agent.go:114 +0x147
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner.(*CpuAgent).update
        C:/gopath/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/miner/agent.go:83 +0x11f

C:\Users\aslaure\Desktop\geth-tutorial-master\nugget1>
```

Comment: This looks like a memory-related panic. How much free memory (i.e. RAM) does your system have?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks that is why its weird, i have 8GB of ram and upon running the miner, and checking the memory utilization, memory usage doesn't even go above 4GB, is there other set-up needed after creating a genesis block and account?